# Child theme enqueue scripts using new functions

Tags: theme-development, child-theme

To enqueue I have used `get_theme_file_uri('/style.css')`. Now I have created a child theme using a generator and it created a code like the following; but it throws a php error with parent-style.

1. Is the code below really needed if I am using `get_theme_file_uri()` in my
   parent theme as it will automatically search for file in child
   theme?
2. I have some `css` code in parent theme (`style.css`). So if I use child theme (which is empty). So will the parent theme style get applied?

`function theme_enqueue_styles() {
        wp_enqueue_style('parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array($parent_style));
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles');`

Thanks

Comment: yes parent theme style applied

Comment: your new or custom css code add your child theme css file but active your child theme

Comment: add this code child theme functions.php file

Comment: // Add Parent Style
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'eventry_child_scripts' );
function eventry_child_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri(). '/style.css' );
}

Comment: please comment your code add this code

Comment: hi solve your problem ? i wetting  your message

Comment: @vikrantzilpe thanks for answers. sorry but i was not able to clear my two questions. The answer is not working for me as it throws error `parent-style` is not defined.

Comment: please send error screenshot

Comment: get_theme_file_uri() in my parent theme as it will automatically search for file in child theme?

Comment: ans: searches in the stylesheet directory before the template directory so themes which inherit from a parent theme can just override one file.

Comment: get_theme_file_path() (for absolute file paths) and get_theme_file_uri() (for URLs) work just like get_template_part() in that they will automatically look in the child theme for that file first, then fallback to the parent theme.

Comment: your second quetion: I have some css code in parent theme (style.css). So if i use child theme(which is empty). so whether the parent theme style will get applied?

Comment: yes parent theme style applied

Comment: @vikrantzilpe it is not applied actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the code below really needed if i am using `get_theme_file_uri()` in
>   my parent theme as it will automatically search for file in child
>   theme?

No. If your parent theme uses `get_theme_file_uri( '/style.css' )`, then when you create a style.css file in your child theme, WordPress will load that *instead*. So it *won't* load the parent theme's styles at all, which I think is related to your next question.

> I have some css code in parent theme (style.css). So if i use child
>   theme(which is empty). so whether the parent theme style will get
>   applied?

If your parent theme uses `get_theme_file_uri( '/style.css' )`, and your child theme has a style.css file, the parent the styles won't get loaded at all. `get_theme_file()` will load the first file it finds, not all of them.

If you want to load the parent theme's styles *and* the child theme's styles, you have two options:

1. Update your parent theme to use `get_parent_theme_file_uri( 'style.css' )`. This will cause WordPress to always load style.css from the parent theme, even if a child theme is activated. If you want to load style.css from the child theme *as well*, then enqueue `get_theme_file_uri( 'style.css' )` from the child theme. Or,
2. Leave your parent theme the way it is, and then enqueue the parent theme's stylesheet from the child theme by enqueueing `get_parent_theme_file_uri( 'style.css' )` from the child theme.